# Splash screen is sometimes distorted and blurred

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I have a splash screen activity with the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_theme</item>
</style>
```

Here is a part of my manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">


    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground" />


    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/shelpwelt_theme" />
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

At some builds all works perfectly but sometimes the splash screen is completely distorted and blurred but just at the first 2-3 seconds. Then when my splash screen activity reaches `onCreate` the theme looks perfectly fine.

Here is the problem:
[image: Here is the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bottom`,`left`,`right`,`top` size to your item.

**Change your drawble file to this :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:opacity="opaque">


<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground" />


<item
    android:bottom="24dp"
    android:left="24dp"
    android:right="24dp"
    android:top="24dp"
    >
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/shelpwelt_theme" />
</item>


</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **gif** file for this case. And after the given time you said, 2-3 sec it wraps the screen size, so the image gets bigger. That's why it get's blurred on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a scaling issue, try to change splash's layout, instead of designing the entire image and set it as a background, design your layout to have two images one for the gray rectangle and the other for the video icon